# best post meta plug in for wordpress suggestion

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for some tools for adding post meta for my post in wordpress and also able to be retrieved.

Would someone suggest which is the best one?

Regards

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for software recommendations - but I would recommend **Advanced Custom Fields**.

Comment: What kind of metadata are you looking to add?

Comment: Try **Cusrom Content Type Manager**

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, you do not need tools, and since this site is more along the lines of helping people code, I will give you some suggestions catered to that end.

I would suggest you look into adding custom fields to your posts. You will have much finer control over adding what you want, than a third-party plugin would allow. It is fairly simple to do, and more information about them can be found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

As to retrieving the data, it is rather simple to do as well. You can find information about retrieving and displaying custom fields data from this link: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/